# Excel formula that can identify 'mixed' sequences of binomially coded data?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

If I have the following rows of data in Excel (5 examples below), whereby data is coded as 1 or 2, does anyone know an Excel formula that can identify/highlight the rows that contain a mixture of 1's and 2's?

**I am only interested in sequences that have a mixture of 1's and 2's.**

For example;

1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2 (this sequence has a mixture)

1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1. (this sequence does not have a mixture)

1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1. (this sequence has a mixture)

2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2. (this sequence does not have a mixture)

1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1 , 2, 1, 1. (this sequence has a mixture)

Currently I use the following formula to highlight/identify the non-mixed sequences with only 1's or 2's;

=IF(ISERROR(FIND("222222222",TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,A1:A9))),FALSE,TRUE)

=IF(ISERROR(FIND("111111111",TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,A1:A9))),FALSE,TRUE)

But now I am in search of a formula that can bring up the mixture sequences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively maybe:

[image]

Formula in `J1`:

```
=MOD(SUM(A1:I1),9)>0
```

Or:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:H1,I1)<8
```

Or:

```
=SUM(A1:I1)<>I1*9
```

Or:

```
=STDEV(A1:I1)>0
```

As a conditional formatting formula I selected `A1:I7` and, for example, used:

```
=STDEV($A1:$I1)>0
```

Comment: Wow @JvdV, these answers are so great, I really appreciate the great effort you've put into helping me out!

Answer (score 4):

If you definitely want to identify *rows* containing a mixture of 1's and 2's, you could use countifs like this:

```
=AND(COUNTIF(A1:J1,1),COUNTIF(A1:J1,2))
```

[image]

If you wanted to be more concise, you could use

```
=VAR(A1:I1)>0
```

(All the answers solve the problem as stated. You could argue that my original answer is robust in the sense that it would cope with blank cells and out-of-range values like 0 or 3)

Comment: Yes! Tom, you won =)

Comment: This is a great solution to the problem Tom, cheers!! :)

Answer (score 4):

One more option, for pre O365 - entered as array formula:

```
=OR(A1:H1<>I1)
```

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

[image]

Comment: A winner in Excel O365 since it doesn't require CSE. Nice game of code-golf right here =)

Comment: If you're playing code golf, maybe =VAR(A1:I1)>0 just pips it.

Answer (score 3):

In `J1` formula copied down :

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:I1-I1)<>0
```

[image]

Edit :

**Explanation of the formula logic**

Take this part of formula to check :

In K1, enter :

=SUMPRODUCT(A1:I1-I1) become >>

=SUMPRODUCT({1,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2}-2) become >>

=SUMPRODUCT({-1,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0}) become >>

=-2

And

In K2, enter :

=SUMPRODUCT(A2:I2-I2) become >>

=SUMPRODUCT({1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}-1) become >>

=SUMPRODUCT({0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}) become >>

=0

Then

Since the range only have 2 number (1 or 2),

if the range minus any one number,

the range (all have the same number) the total sum must equal to "0",

else, "not 0"

Follow this logic, you can have another solution similar to Tom Sharpe's suggestion formula in using COUNTIF function

```
=COUNTIF(A1:J1,I1)<>COUNT(A1:J1)
```

Comment: Wow, I like the simplicity of this solution.

Comment: It's neat isn't it? I had at the back of my mind that there might be other approaches using differences, but went for the more obvious one.

Comment: @bosco_yip - this is a super answer but I feel it requires some brief explanation to the method.

Comment: @Robin Mackenzie, It is a simple formula. Take this part of formula to check =SUMPRODUCT(A1:I1-I1). Since the range only have 2 number (1 or 2), if the range minus any one number, the range (all have the same number) the total sum must equal to "0", else "not 0"

Comment: @bosco_yip - it is simple to you; and I also understand how it works - but the utility of it is not necessarily clear to the people who read your answer and think to themselves 'cool, but how does it work...'. Why don't you edit your answer and provide a little more explanation?

Comment: @Robin Mackenzie, thanks for your idea, I have edited to my post

Comment: I really appreciate everyone's great help with this question!!!!

Answer (score 3):

If you have O365, you could use:

```
=COUNT(UNIQUE(A1:I1,TRUE))=2
```

will return `TRUE` if mixed, else `FALSE`